# How to process large .kryo files for graph data using TinkerPop/Gremlin

Tags: apache-spark, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, kryo

I am new to Apache TinkerPop.
I have done some basic stuff like installing TinkerPop Gremlin console, creating graph .kryo file, loaded it in gremlin console and executed some basic gremlin queries. All good till now.

But i wanted to check how can we process .kryo files which are very much large in size says more than 1000GB. If i create a single .kryo file, loading it in console(or using some code) is not feasible i think.

Is there any way we can deal with graph data which is pretty huge in size?
basically i have some graph based data stored in Amazon Neptune DB, i want to take it out and store it in some files(e.g .kryo) and process later for gremlin queries. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Kyro which is Java specific, I would recommend using something more language agnostic such as CSV files. If you are using Amazon Neptune you can use the Neptune Export tool to export your data as CSV files.

- [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/machine-learning-data-export.html)
- [Git repo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-export)
- [Cloud Formation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/machine-learning-data-export-service.html)

Comment: Regardless of file type for the export, how would the graph be divided among multiple files?  Wouldn't edges become disconnected from their vertices if they were exported to one file, but the vertex on one end landed in the other exported file?

Comment: The Neptune CSV format puts all vertex information in one (or more) vertex files (which a vertex specific header row). Likewise, all edges are placed into one (or more) CSV files with an edge specific header row. When reloading, the bulk loader will load all vertices before trying to load and create any edges.